# adding a menuitem with image on Menubar

Tags: java, menuitem, zk

Trying to add menuitem with image and having no label in it.

```
<borderlayout> <north> <menubar>
<menuitem image="/test/image.gif" onclick="@command('doSomething')"/> <menuitem &gt;="" <="" menubar=""> </north> . . </borderlayout>
```

if i add a image without any label it cuts the image from both sides(right and bottom) ,and if i use some text in label the full image is shown ,

my problem is i have to show a menuitem with only image on it and no text. I can't change the size of image.

The following code works but i don't want to add label

```
<borderlayout> <north> <menubar>
<menuitem label="a" image="/test/image.gif" onclick="@command('doSomething')"/> <menuitem &gt;="" <="" menubar=""> </north> . . </borderlayout>
```

can anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Did you try to set width/height ?

Comment: yes but it's not working.

Comment: I don't know whether it's a bug or not but anyway you can play with css padding styles for `z-menuitem-inner-m` and `z-menuitem-btn` classes as a workaround. I've got best results with `padding-right: 0` for `z-menuitem-inner-m` and `padding-left` equal to the width of the menuitem image for `z-menuitem-btn`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is what you want.

If you cannot change the size of the image, you have to use css to adjust the image to fit in menuitem.

Here's an example that use css3 property `background-size`

```
<zk>
  <style>
    .shrink .z-menuitem-img{
      background-size:24px 24px;
    }
  </style>
  <menubar>
    <menu label="test">
      <menupopup>
        <menuitem sclass="shrink" image="https://www.google.com.tw/images/icons/product/chrome-128.png" />
        <menuitem                 image="https://www.google.com.tw/images/icons/product/chrome-128.png" />
      </menupopup>
    </menu>
  </menubar>
</zk>
```

you can see this example runs in [ZkFiddle](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/1l6tehq/7-put-a-large-image-in-menuitem)